# Install phpunit on windows without composer won't work

Tags: php, phpunit, environment-variables, phar

I'm trying to install phpunit manually on my windows machine. I don't use composer, so I have to install it manually with a .phar file. I'm following the instructions from the official documentation:

https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#windows

I've done every step, but it won't work. `phpunit --version` will throw me the message `'phpunit' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` Can someone Help me?

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit with XAMPP 3.2.2 and PHP 7.1.1.

**EDIT:**

My phpunit.cmd file location is  `C:\xampp\php\phar\phpunit.cmd`.
The file contains the code `@php "%~dp0phpunit.phar" %*`. I've added `;C:xampp\php\phar` to my PATH variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make Windows recognize any command, you must put the binary's path in the relevant environment variable (PATH). Before that you need to create some kind of file Windows can run natively (i.e. not a .phar – can be a command line / batch file or executable). Here are instructions:

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.phar.windows

**Edit:** If following the above instructions, it's also important to make sure that `php` itself is part of the PATH environment variable, so that it's possible to execute commands like `php phpunit.phar`.

Comment: I've made every step in that tutorial, there are the same steps described in the phpunit docs (see the link in my question). Only thing I'm not sure about is, which exact environment variable i have to change. Is it the path variable for the user or is it a system variable?

Comment: Either should work. I use the user variables for things like this.

Comment: mhh ok... and i have to do nothing more? I've never worked with .phar files before. I just can't figure out where I did a mistake

Comment: For the purposes of this example, think of .phar files like regular .php files. You need PHP to run them. So your Windows command-line file needs to use PHP, like: php phpunit.phar. However, the php command must also be in the environment variables, otherwise it will fail. If you made a phpunit.cmd file like in the instructions, can you post it in your question?

Comment: I've edited my question. What exactly do you mean with "the php command must also be in the environment variables"?

Comment: I got it! I had to set the PHP environment variable. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant by 'the php command must also be in the environment variables'. Glad it worked out :)